# Is there a simple way to filter XML datatype in SQL-Server?

Tags: sql-server, query, xml

I have a table in an SQL-Server database, containing a column, called `XmlMsg`, being of the datatype `Xml`:

"Columns" definition:
[image]

I would like to filter on that column, which first I did using "simple" text filtering:

```
WHERE XmlMsg LIKE '%status%'
```

This resulted in following error message:

```
Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of like function.
```

So I decided to use another way, as indicated in [this official URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-full-text-search-with-xml-columns?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
WHERE CONTAINS(XmlMsg,'status')
```

This yielded following error message:

```
Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view
'<Table_Name>' because it is not full-text indexed.
```

I can't modify the database structure (so adding an extra index is out of the question).

Is there a simple way (without needing to know all about `XPath`) to write a `WHERE`-clause on such column?

For your information: I'm not looking for a complete filtering in SQL: I just want to get a simply filtered list of entries, which I will then copy to Notepad++ and do further filtering over there. The big point is that there are over 250,000 entries in that table and I don't want to overload the database by fetching such large query results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple way (without needing to know all about XPath) to write a WHERE-clause on such column?

Short answer?  No.
You must use the Right Tool for the Right Job.

```
XML != text 
XML != free text 
XML = XML
```

This is why SQL is *not* littered with all the String-handling functions we find in our favourite programming languages.

The XPath filtering constructs exist for a *reason*; learn to use them.
(Free Lesson #1: Avoid *starting* your XPaths with "**//**").

The problem with *starting* an XPath with `//`, a.k.a. `descendant-or-self::node()`, is that it means "scan the entire document, finding *any and all* nodes that match the XPath I've given you".  In a large document, that can mean a huge overhead, which is especially bad if you already *know* the structure you're working with.  Too many people mistakenly think it means "start at the root element".

Comment: Isn't there some function, which can convert `XML` into simple text?

Comment: There is, but you would lose all the *structure* that XML gives you.  
If you were looking for `id = 123`, you could not tell the different between `<prosecutor id="123" name="Barney"/>` and `<defence_counsel name="Fred" id="123"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

Phil W. is right. The proper way would be doing what [he suggests](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/338059).

For a quick hack, you might try converting the XML to string and then using `LIKE`. However, I wouldn't expect performance to be particularly great:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
 ExEmEl XML
);

INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES  ('<root><status>online</status></root>'),
  ('<root><name>John</name></root>');

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ExEmEl) LIKE '%Status%'
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9mODTd8a).